# How do I go scroll to an an anchor or div on an xpage if using validateRequired for a radio button group?

Tags: validation, radio-button, xpages

I would just use the following if I wanted to jump to a place on the html page (e.g. on the click of a submit button if I were validating with CSJS):

> XSP.getElementById(elementID).scrollIntoView()

I just don't see a place to put the client side script. The validation works fine and displays my error message. How do I do this using validateRequired?

If the answer is to use validateExpression, please proved an example of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

There is a awesome custom control explained by Tommy Valand, I suppose meets your criteria:

http://dontpanic82.blogspot.sg/2011/07/custom-control-for-enhanced-validation.html

Comment: I looked through that, but it's pretty complicated for what I am trying to do. I have various ways of field validation, some based upon the requirements of the project. (ie they want some validation to occur on typing, some on tabbing to the next field, and some on clicking the submit button). So, I'm all set except that I can't figure out how to bring the focus to a field or scroll to a place on the page when I use validators.